# How to configure LVM on my Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I need to configure physical volumes and LVM on my Ubuntu desktop. I worked with my virtual boxes, could not upgrade them due to insufficient space.
My lsblk

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0 132,1M  1 loop /snap/postman/81
loop1    7:1    0   3,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/77
loop2    7:2    0  53,7M  1 loop /snap/core18/782
loop3    7:3    0  89,3M  1 loop /snap/core/6673
loop4    7:4    0   2,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/260
loop5    7:5    0  91,1M  1 loop /snap/core/6531
loop6    7:6    0   3,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/81
loop7    7:7    0  14,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/206
loop8    7:8    0  34,7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
loop9    7:9    0  53,7M  1 loop /snap/core18/941
loop10   7:10   0     4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/352
loop11   7:11   0  35,3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
loop12   7:12   0  14,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/258
loop13   7:13   0 140,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop14   7:14   0  14,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop15   7:15   0 140,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
loop16   7:16   0   3,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/70
loop17   7:17   0  34,8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
loop18   7:18   0  17,9M  1 loop /snap/pdftk/9
loop19   7:19   0  14,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/254
loop20   7:20   0  53,7M  1 loop /snap/core18/970
loop21   7:21   0 140,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
loop22   7:22   0   151M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/40
loop23   7:23   0  1008K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/57
loop24   7:24   0  1008K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/61
loop25   7:25   0 143,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
loop26   7:26   0  89,4M  1 loop /snap/core/6818
loop27   7:27   0     4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/406
loop28   7:28   0   151M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/36
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 465,3G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
sdc      8:32   0 111,8G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 111,8G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

There are no physical volumes

```
pvscan
  No matching physical volumes found
```

How to create LVM?
I guess that first step would be `pvcreate`

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/sdb
  Physical volume "/dev/sdb" successfully created.
```

Now I need to check

```
sudo pvs
  PV         VG Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
  /dev/sdb      lvm2 ---  931,51g 931,51g
```

Done.

My goal is to create the partitions on

```
/dev/sdb
```

and leave the others untouched.
What is the next step towards the LVM?

Comment: In LVM the equivalent to a partition is a logical volume. Have you already read one of the many tutorials (and/or videos) on LVM? If not, that's your next step towards LVM. If so, please feel free to ask a specific question; But search first because it's probably already been answered. Unfortunately, as-is your question is too broad.

Comment: Ok,can you suggest some good tutorial?

Comment: pvcreate, vgcreate, lvcreate, mkfs.ext4, mount